# What is a Cacodaemon in D&D 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

The *Fiendish Codex I* mentions Ahrimanes, the Chief of the Cacodaemons (p.155). But what exactly a Cacodaemon is goes unmentioned. They're mentioned in 4e, AD&D 1e and Pathfinder, but as far as I can tell they're not in 3.5e. Have I missed them somewhere? Or is Ahrimanes' appearance just a reference to his earlier appearance in the AD&D Monster Manual II?

Comment: [Wikipedia indicates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacodemon) (*without* citation) that cacodaemons were revised into cacoloths for 3.x. May be an avenue of research.

Comment: Perhaps http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/050/5/3/doom_cacodemon_sprite_by_ness71-d39wccf.gif ?

Comment: @Yamikuronue No, that cacodemon got its name from the existing English word ("cacodemon" just means "evil spirit"), and got its art "inspiration" from the cover of [an AD&D book showing an Astral Dreadnought](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Cacodemon); meanwhile, cacodaemons have been in D&D since before Doom existed.

Comment: @Yamikuronue That's what they are like in Pathfinder. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_demon_lords#Ahrimanes Ahrimanes' entry on Wikipedia mentions The Book of Fiends, but from what I can tell that's a Green Ronin printing, and as such is a third party printing.

Comment: @sevensideddie I was joking, sorry, should have put a smilie face :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### "Cacodemon" simply means "evil demon"

The word itself is of Greek derivation, and since "daimon" referred to spirits of all stripe in Greek, a qualifier such as agatho- or kako- was necessary to distinguish whether one was referring to a benevolent or evil spirit.

### In the context of D&D, "cacodemon" and "cacodaemon" refer to particularly terrible demons

...but not as a specific caste. Rather, the spell *cacodemon* was a magic-user spell in early editions of the game which brought forth a dangerous fiend (a nalfeshnee, marilith or balor). The spell was phased out during the general purge of "unholy" imagery in 2nd Edition, and by the time 3rd Edition rolled around was replaced by general-purpose calling spells.

### Cacodaemons have nothing to do with yugoloths

Original research by a Wikipedia user back in 2006, likely a misreading of "canoloth" or an adaptation of houseruled canon. Wikipedia's D&D pages tend to propagate this sort of fanon rapidly throughout the web thanks to the number of scraper pages that distribute their content.

### So what is Ahrimanes?

As you surmised, a Monster Manual II holdover, a placeholder filling the ranks.

Comment: There are also (I'm not kidding) [Cocoadaemons](https://web.archive.org/web/20131118095147/http://creaturecatalog.enworld.org/cc/converted/view_c.php?CreatureID=2124), demons made of chocolate. They are opposed by (again, not kidding) [Chocodevas](https://web.archive.org/web/20131118095152/http://creaturecatalog.enworld.org/cc/converted/view_c.php?CreatureID=2125). Guess what they're made of. Both of these creatures were originally found in Polyhedron #23 back in 1984.

Comment: I looked at the Canoloth entry, but the Canoloth looks like an entirely different creature. It's doglike, so the Cano part likely came from Canine, and it's been featured as early as the Planescape MC II (and it's found in MM III in 3.5e).

Comment: Alright, clearly you focused on the wrong part of my answer. There is no such creature as a "cacodemon." The Wikipedia contributor who claimed that it was adapted as a yugoloth was wrong.